# maxAgeSeconds in sw-toolbox not working

Tags: service-worker, progressive-web-apps, sw-toolbox

I'm using sw-toolbox for building progressive web app. All resources are getting cached as expected but they are not expiring on putting maxAgeSeconds.

```
toolbox.router.get("/test/(.*)", toolbox.cacheFirst, {
    cache: {
        maxEntries: 5, name: "list", maxAgeSeconds: 300, debug: !0
    }
});
```

I have used `CacheFirst` Strategy, and verified that resources are kicking in through service worker cache.

Comment: It's best to go through the `sw-toolbox` issue tracker for this sort of thing, rather than Stack Overflow. In particular, it sounds like you might be running into https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-toolbox/issues/164. It's best to follow up there.

Comment: @JeffPosnick Already gone through this issue #164, but seems like it bit different. In my case, I can see number of other cache storage (Deleted caches) in Application Tab->IndexDB  which is not getting return by this statement caches.keys().then(function(e) { console.log(e); }).

Comment: Could you follow up with details in a new issue on the tracker? Thanks.

Comment: @JeffPosnick #207 has been filed for the same.

Comment: there is no comma between "list" and maxAgeSeconds ?